# What does pluralize mean/do?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

This came from the Django tutorial:

```
<li>{{ choice.choice_text }} - {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
```

Like I said, what does 'pluralize' mean and what does it do?

Comment: It returns an `s` if the number in question is greater than `1`. So if `choice.votes` is greater than `1`, `vote` gets an `s` added to it making it `votes`.

Answer (score 2):

`pluralize` is a filter, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#pluralize)...

> Returns a plural suffix if the value is not 1. By default, this suffix is 's'.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a profile which shows votes but initially you have initialized votes but what if you have only one vote it will again show 1 votes but to remove s we use the above syntax

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).